# Rails wants to save an attr_accessor attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

have some custom attr_accessor in my model.

When I try to create a new model using the params[:model] I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: entity_select, office_select):

class Expedient < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :enterprise
  has_many :document

  attr_accessor :entity_select
  attr_accessor :office_select

...
```

I suppose Rails know that those are att_accessor and should not be saved on the model in the database.

Or not ?

I'm using this attr_accessor for creating some help field using simple_form:

```
<%= f.input :entity_select,:label => 'Entity', :input_html => {:class => "span2"}, :wrapper => :prepend do %>
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span><%= f.input_field :entity_select, :class => "span2 typeahead_entity", :id_selected => '99', :id => 'typeahead_centre'%>
<%end%>
```

I need a special text input for a typeahed, but I want to create this input using simple_form, like other 'real' fields, that's why I'm using a 'not real attribute'...

thanks,

### EDIT:

The error is not when saving, just before, when assigning the params to the model attributes here:

```
    @expedient=Expedient.new.attributes=params[:expedient]
```

Comment: Isn't that saying it needs to be accessible? I don't think that it's trying to be persisted.

Comment: you're right, I've updated/edited the question. thanks

Comment: Didn't my comment answer the question?! Make them accessible.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not following you here ... How ? Do you mean to just include them with attr_accessible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `entity_select` and `office_select` attributes accessible:

```
class Expedient < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Add:
  attr_accessible :entity_select, :office_select
```

Comment: now I can accept the Answer. I thought that attr_accessible where not needed for attr_accessor when you make a mass-assign. Thanks

Comment: @mongeta No problem. I *think* the mass-assignment stuff just checks setter methods to see if they've been accessible-ized, although I don't recall for sure.